# trapz integration on dataframe index after grouping

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scipy

I have some data and I want to first group by some interval the Target column and then integrate the target column by index spacing.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy import integrate


df = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.array([100, 105.4, 108.3, 111.1, 113, 114.7, 120, 125, 129, 130, 131, 133,135,140, 141, 142]),
                   'B': np.array([11, 11.8, 12.3, 12.8, 13.1,13.6, 13.9, 14.4, 15, 15.1, 15.2, 15.3, 15.5, 16, 16.5, 17]),
                   'C': np.array([55, 56.3, 57, 58, 59.5, 60.4, 61, 61.5, 62, 62.1, 62.2, 62.3, 62.5, 63, 63.5, 64]),
                   'Target': np.array([4000, 4200.34, 4700, 5300, 5800, 6400, 6800, 7200, 7500, 7510, 7530, 7540, 7590,
                                      8000, 8200, 8300])})

df['y'] = df.groupby(pd.cut(df.iloc[:, 3], np.arange(0, max(df.iloc[:, 3]) + 100, 100))).sum().apply(lambda g: integrate.trapz(g.Target, x = g.index))
```

Above code gives me:

```
AttributeError: ("'Series' object has no attribute 'Target'", 'occurred at index A')
```

If I try this:

```
colNames = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'Target']
df['z'] = df.groupby(pd.cut(df.iloc[:, 3], np.arange(0, max(df.iloc[:, 3]) + 100, 100))).sum().apply(lambda g: integrate.trapz(g[colNames[3]], x = g.index))
```

I get:

```
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

....
KeyError: ('Target', 'occurred at index A')
```

Comment: Since series have only one column, the column name is kinda irrelevant. You can use `g.values` to get the values at the series or `g.index.values` to get the values of its index

Comment: Can you produce the expected output for more clarity?

Comment: Are you trying to get in each row the integral between the first interval and the current interval? On the other hand, you are grouping by the column 'Target', not by the 'A' as you said. An slice of your data before apply is
`                       A     B      C   Target
Target                                       
(0.0, 100.0]        0.0   0.0    0.0      0.0
(100.0, 200.0]      0.0   0.0    0.0      0.0
...
(8100.0, 8200.0]  141.0  16.5   63.5   8200.0
(8200.0, 8300.0]  142.0  17.0   64.0   8300.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several problems in your code:

- You have created a copy of your dataframe  with a categorical index than I think `integrate.trapz` cannot deal with.
- with apply, you are applying integrate.trapz to each row. That makes no sense. For that reason I asked in my comment if you need, in each row, the integral from 0 to Target value in such row.

If you want transform you data by intervals of 100 in the column 'Target' from 0 as you have done, first you can get the sum by intervals of 'Target' from 0 to 100

```
>>>i_df = df.groupby(pd.cut(df.iloc[:, 3], np.arange(0, max(df.iloc[:, 3]) + 100, 100))).sum()
```

Then you get the trapezoidal integral of column 'Target' with intervals of 100

```
>>>integrate.trapz(i_df['Target'], dx=100)
10242034.0
```

You cannot use x=i_df.index because the (internal in trapz) operation substraction is not defined for intervals, and you have created an intervals index.
If you need to use the dataframe index you must reset it.

```
>>>i_df = df.groupby(pd.cut(df.iloc[:, 3], np.arange(0, max(df.iloc[:, 3]) + 100, 100))).sum().reset_index(drop=True)
>>>integrate.trapz(i_df['Target'], x=100*i_df.index)
10242034.0
```